Proyecto nuevo de expo y react native no funciona los eventos
He creado un proyecto nuevo de react native expo con el comando "npx create-expo-app appPrueba".
Con versión de node 18.20.2 en Windows 10.
Solo modifique el app.js del nuevo proyecto para probar el evento onpress de la siguiente manera:
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const prueba = () => {
    console.log(`mierda`)
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={prueba}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

El package.js está de esta manera:
{
  "name": "appblomifinal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

Cuando ejecuto el proyecto con npx expo start y leo el QR con expo go(2.30.11) en mi dispositivo físico, presiono varias veces en el texto y me muestra el log, solo por 2 segundos y luego deja de funcionar. No sale nada en la consola, ni error ni warning, pero no funciona.
No entiendo como un proyecto nuevo de expo simplemente no funciona.

Por que no usas View primero y dentro de eso agregas el botón con touchableopacity y StatusBar fuera de touchableopacity
